# accept POST request from specific site in django

Tags: python, django, django-csrf

I want to serve files via HTTP, but want to accept requests only from the same site (that's working fine) AND from an specific external app (not written in python nor django).

Is this possible? I'd prefer not to disable CSRF protection for the view.

If disabling CSRF protection is the only way, how can I prevent request from other external sites?

Comment: Is your other app capable of somehow authenticating itself so it could request and receive the right CSRF token from a different view before the request? Then it could use the normal view in the normal way by simply sending it.

Comment: How about checking for the referrer in the request,

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist It's maybe capable of login... but I'd prefer to avoid the overhead.

Comment: @Anup That's what I'm thinking too, hence the second question. I suppose I have to use `@csrf_exempt` and handle the request info in the view.